# About Griffin's dialogue "Where there is death, there will always be death"

Tags: men-in-black, men-in-black-3

In the ending of *Men In Black 3*, it depicts J's father's death as sort of replacing K's death. (as stated in Griffin's dialogue). But K also kills Borris, who didn't die in the original timeline or the altered one (where Borris kills K). So whose death is Borris replacing? And wouldn't it have been possible to save J's father instead and just have Borris die to cater for K's death?

Comment: Temporal mechanics give me a headache.

Comment: It may be argued that Young Boris' death was inconsequential as the timeline was restored by that point (deploying ArcNet and shooting off Boris' arm were conditions to that according to Griffin) and since the Old one was already dead, timeline is not affected drastically from that point. Which is totally not the case with K. It's easier if one thinks of it as two altered timelines, yet one is dependent on the outcome of the other. SO Col. Edwards dies in order to restore the K/J timeline, not the K/Boris one. Or, as Revenant wrote after Chief O'Brian: *I hate temporal mechanics*

Answer (score -1):

As J's dad had died in the original timeline, young K's death in the rebooted timeline would have replaced J's dad's(meaning that J's dad was alive in the version of the timeline where Earth was invaded.  So, yay?).  By this logic, young Boris's death should have replaced both J's dad's and K's deaths.  However, because young Boris killed J's dad before K could kill him, this means that someone else's life was spared.  This is the only explanation that supports the "where there is death, there will always be death" idea.